# Throwing an exception more than once loses its original stack trace

Tags: c#

I have been playing around with Exceptions to learn more about how I should use them properly. So far, I know that `throw` keeps the original stack trace; `throw new CustomException(...)` is generally used when wanting to add more information about the exception that took place or add/change the message, or even change the type of Exception itself; and `throw ex` should never ever be used, unless I want to lose the original stack trace.

So I wrote a small program where I could catch and rethrow an exception several times while adding something to the original message.

```
public class Sample
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Tester().FirstCall();
    }
}

public class Tester
{
    public void FirstCall()
    {
        try
        {
            SecondCall();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }

    public void SecondCall()
    {
        try
        {
            ThirdCall();
        }
        catch (GoodException ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message, ex);
        }
    }

    public void ThirdCall()
    {
        try
        {
            FourthCall();
        }
        catch (ArithmeticException ae)
        {
            throw new GoodException("Arithmetic mistake: " + ae.Message, ae);
        }
    }

    public void FourthCall()
    {
        int d = 0;
        int x = 10 / d;
    }
}
```

Where `GoodException` is a custom exception [implemented correctly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182151.aspx).

I'm expecting the console to display something like this:

```
   at PlayingWithExceptions.Tester.FourthCall() in d:\Projects\PlayingWithExceptions\PlayingWithExceptions\Trying.cs:line 67
   at PlayingWithExceptions.Tester.ThirdCall() in d:\Projects\PlayingWithExceptions\PlayingWithExceptions\Trying.cs:line 59
   at PlayingWithExceptions.Tester.SecondCall() in d:\Projects\PlayingWithExceptions\PlayingWithExceptions\Trying.cs:line 41
   at PlayingWithExceptions.Tester.FirstCall() in d:\Projects\PlayingWithExceptions\PlayingWithExceptions\Trying.cs:line 25
Arithmetic mistake: Attempted to divide by zero.
```

But instead I'm getting this:

```
   at PlayingWithExceptions.Tester.SecondCall() in d:\Projects\PlayingWithExceptions\PlayingWithExceptions\Trying.cs:line 41
   at PlayingWithExceptions.Tester.FirstCall() in d:\Projects\PlayingWithExceptions\PlayingWithExceptions\Trying.cs:line 25
Arithmetic mistake: Attempted to divide by zero.
```

For some reason it only goes as far as the second call. Even though I'm passing the caught exception as an `InnerException`, the stack trace is still lost. I'm aware that if I just wrote `throw` instead of throwing a new exception, I could keep the original stack trace, but if I do that I won't be able to change the original message (which was the whole point of this exercise).

So my question is, what can I do to change the Exception message AND keep the original stack trace the whole way?

**EDIT**: Since an exception should not be used logic control and only caught once, the proper way to keep the original stack trace AND show the new message is to wrap the FourthCall in a try/catch (where the new Exception with its message is generated), and catch it only once all the way up in the FirstCall.

Comment: you should never rethrow exceptions. bad practice. why catch them in the first place? It is also expensive to do this and this is exactly what happens when you do so - you lose the stack trace. In addition you should NEVER use exception as a flow of logic. Exceptions are just that... exceptions, you don't use them to flow your code logic

Comment: Suppose that I'm in a big project with business layers, data layers, etc, and I want to keep track of where the exception came from?

Comment: you write them to error logs or db's or whatever to log them. why do you want to know where it came from? When you catch the exception - you log it there and then. The consumer just needs to know if the operation/call succeeded and if not, then do something about it like show to the user "An error occurred" but you don't give them the technical details about it for many reasons (i.e security and UI friendliness).

Comment: Side note: "rethrow" is likely mean `throw` for readers, consider changing title to make it clear that you want to throw new exception and keep stack.

Comment: @Ahmedilyas I see, I was not aware of that. Like I mentioned in the question I only recently started learning Exceptions so I was unaware this was bad practice. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: This should help you understand it better: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264997.aspx  - and BTW, this is how exceptions work.. it does get messier like you are discovering. It's why you... don't do it for many reasons

Comment: @Ahmedilyas I'll give that a read then. And out of curiosity, in my sample code where would it be best to catch the exception (only once)? When calling the FourthCall or the FirstCall?

Comment: First call.....since after all, it is the first call in the whole process right?

Comment: @Ahmedilyas Ugh, of course... forget I asked that. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The stack trace isn't "lost" it's pushed into the InnerException, just like you told it to be. The "outer" exception in this case, did not participate in the call chain of the Inner exception - it's a brand new exception which originates in SecondCall, so that's the beginning of its stack trace.

And yes, the commenters are correct. To control your messaging, you won't do that by trying to set the message in the Exception object - Exceptions should be handled by code, messages are for users. So, you'll log the message, display it to the user, something like that.

Comment: Adding `e.InnerException` did show the rest of the stack trace, although "messier" than I expected. But reading the comments now I know something like this shouldn't be done in the first place, better to use logs. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, and we don't live in a perfect world. I've seen libraries that eat 'original' exceptions and give you back a LibraryException or whatever, and you have to check the Inner on those sometimes. Exceptions are an area where theory and practice collide.

Comment: Right exactly @Jasmine. Plus, it makes it soooo difficult to figure out exactly where the exception is being thrown from as many developers may write it in a different way or the same developer thinks something else during the whole catching/swallowing/rethrowing... time comes in production, you are lost to figure out where the hell its being thrown from truly and what happened...

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it still relevant for you. Just use the keyword "***throw***" without the exception append to it , then the trace will not be lost and the original exception will be throws. not as inner.