# What problems do you see with passing exception handling to a single method?

Tags: c#, exception

I'm currently working with some code that is used in client server communication.

I has a lot (around 50) of the following `try-catch` blocks

```
try
{
    return GetLogFiles(date);
}
catch (TimeoutException ex)
{
    this.GetLogger("GetAllLogs").Error("C is not answering!", ex);
}
catch (ConnectionInterruptedException ex)
{
    this.GetLogger("GetAllLogs").Error("Connection interrupted", ex);
}
catch (ActionNotSupportedException ex)
{
    this.GetLogger().Error("Software-version not comaptible!", ex);
    throw new VersionNotCompatibleException();
}
catch (EndpointNotFoundException ex)
{
    this.GetLogger().Error("Problem with network, connection to core is lost!", ex);
}
catch (CommunicationException ex)
{
    this.GetLogger().Error("Not expected communication-exception was thrown:", ex);
}
```

This makes for a LOT of code that is more or less always the same.

Now I thought about refactoring all the catch blocks into a method and just call it. Like

```
try
{
    return GetLogFiles(date);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    ExceptionHandling(string operation, Exception ex)
}


private void ExceptionHandling(string operation, Exception ex)
{
    if (ex is TimeoutException)
    {
        this.GetLogger(operation).Error("C is not answering!", ex);
    }
    else if (ex is ConnectionInterruptedException)
    {
        this.GetLogger(operation).Error("Connection interrupted", ex);
    }
    else if (ex is CommunicationObjectFaultedException)
    {
        this.GetLogger(operation).Error("Core is not answering!", ex);
    }
    else if (ex is FaultException)
    {
        this.GetLogger(operation).Error("C is not answering!", ex);
    }
    else if (ex is ActionNotSupportedException)
    {
        this.GetLogger().Error("Software-version not comaptible!", ex);
        throw new VersionNotCompatibleException();
    }
    else if (ex is EndpointNotFoundException)
    {
        this.GetLogger().Error("Problem with network, connection is lost!", ex);
    }
    else if (ex is CommunicationException)
    {
        this.GetLogger().Error("Not expected communication-exception was thrown:", ex);
    }
    else
    {
        this.GetLogger().Error("Unknown exception was thrown:", ex);
        throw new Exception("Unknown exception occured during request handling", ex);
    }
}
```

None of the codeparts does any ordinary handling in case of an exception, i.e. they get logged and that's it.

What problems do you see with extracting the exception part into its own method?

Comment: The only problem i see, is why not use a 3rd party error logger

Comment: @Alex We're far from seeing this as a problem at the moment - at least I am ;)

Comment: You don't gain anything from separating the error handling the way you do. Actually, your code is even longer now....

Comment: I have the try catch block 50 times in this class. Refactoring it will make it about 1300 LOC shorter ;)

Comment: Are you not re-factoring at the wrong level? Why are you leaving those 50 try/catches in place and calling out to a separate method within the catch rather than moving the try/catch itself into a separate function and leaving the structure of the catch clauses in place?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem I see is that you're rethrowing the exception if it isn't one you expect, making you lose the real stack trace, plus using `Exception` in your catch is a very broad thing to do.

Lines of code isn't the real issue, and yes making things DRY is a good thing to do but its more likely that the thing that needs making dry is the `GetLogFiles` function to include the error handling inside of that, not the exception handler.

Comment: Should passing `ex` when rethrowing not keep the stack trace? Also when the current try catch doesn't handle an unknown exception it would pass it upwards as well.

Comment: @MarkusDeibel - You get *a* stack trace, but not the exact one that caused the error.

Comment: But doesn't the second parameter of `throw new Exception("String", ex)` just signify the _inner_ exception?  In my understanding the innerException is an unaltered copy of the original one I'm passing into the ExceptionHandling method. That's also my interpretation of this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/23923541/2137237 (and the comments). So the stack trace in there should be unaltered.

Comment: @MarkusDeibel - You're right, [that constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/804f22sf(v=vs.110).aspx) does include it in the inner exception which may be acceptable for your use case, I don't always have faith that I can trust other developers to delve that far down when trying to fix an exception but then that constructor exists for a reason so that might be acceptable. It would appear as though there isn't enough information about your dev teams procedures here to make a justified decision and an internal decision may be a better idea.

Comment: (Again, I do wonder if refactoring `GetLogFiles` would be more suitable)

Comment: you're probably right, but then we will need to refactor also the other 30 or 40 methods that have this long try-catch attached. Regarding the debugging habits, I rely on having the information logged. Even if lower support tiers don't catch it I can fall back to it, so in the current situation I take it as sufficient, but will follow your advice and dicuss it internally as well.

Answer (score 0):

it's better to do that like this:

```
public class MyException : Exception
{
   public MyException(Exception ex)
   {
        // handle exception
   }
}
```

and

```
try
{
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   throw new MyException(ex)
}
```

Comment: how would introducing a user Exception improve the situation? What from my example would you replace with it?

Comment: don't repeat yourself , you can take log of all of exceptions in your application in one place and other actions, such as an Integrated error handling , etc.

Comment: Do I get this right? You would have `GetLogFiles` throw `MyException` and having the MyException object contain the original exception as innerException? But this would mean having to refactor GetLogFiles (and all its siblings) and already catching all the actual exceptions there - again duplicating the handling code.